# Draw legend on a plot using different colors

Tags: r, legend

```
x <- matrix(seq(1,10,by=0.1),ncol=5,nrow=5)
colnames(x) <- letters[1:5]
rownames(x) <- letters[6:10]
plot(hclust(t(dist(x))))
```

[image]

I have a data frame :

```
df <- data.frame(Rows = letters[6:10],value=c("L","L","L","L","N"))
df
  Rows value
1    f     L
2    g     L
3    h     L
4    i     L
5    j     N
```

I want to draw a colored legend in the above plot below the x axis.
like rowname f has value L ,so part of legend below it in plot should be colored as 'red' and likewise h,i,g and  but legend below j label in the plot should have 'blue'.

It should look something like this :

[image]

I tried using image.plot but not getting desired result.
Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Using 'legend' function, is there a way to create the above plot??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a somewhat near solution to this problem : 
The result plot can be drawn using `text` function

```
df <- data.frame(Rows = letters[6:10],value=c("L","L","L","L","N"))
x <- matrix(seq(1,10,by=0.1),ncol=5,nrow=5)
colnames(x) <- letters[1:5]
rownames(x) <- letters[6:10]
plot(hclust(t(dist(x))))
axis(1,at=seq(1,length(rownames(x)),1),labels=FALSE)
text(seq(1,length(rownames(x)),1),labels="\u2594",col=c(rep("red",2),"blue",rep("red",2)),cex=25,par("usr")[3]+0.005)
legend("topright",legend=c("L","N"),col=c("red","blue"))
```

unicode "\u2594" is used in text to create a box image.